# How to simulate intermittent demand in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, random

**Context:** Intermittent demand refers to (demand) time-series data that is characterized by the presence of periods with zero demand. These non-zero demands are often small yet highly variable. Intermittent demand has many applications and poses challenges to many traditional forecasting and control systems.

**How do I generate random samples of intermittent demand in MATLAB?**

In R's [`tsintermittent`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=tsintermittent) package, there is a function to simulate intermittent demand called [`simID()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tsintermittent/versions/1.9/topics/simID).
I am not aware of any built-in MATLAB functions to accomplish this (& I highly doubt they exist).

Relevant parameters include *variability* and *intermittency*.

Comment: Seems this is encouraged: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Justin I was just about to post [that link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Why the downvotes...?

Comment: @LuisMendo   I don't know. I'm happy to edit the Q or A as needed to maximize value to the community on this.  Comments, suggestions, etc. are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function can be replicated in MATLAB with the Statistics toolbox using [`nbinrnd()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nbinrnd.html) and [`binornd()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/binornd.html).

The syntax is `[d] = simID(n, obs, adi, cv2, level)` with

**n**: number of demand streams to create
**obs**: number of time periods to simulate
**adi**: average demand interval (time periods)
**cv2**: [coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation) squared
**level**: average of nonzero demands
**d**: 'n' x 'obs' matrix with the specified demand streams

This explicitly assumes that non-zero demand arrivals follow a [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) and the non-zero demands a [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).<sup>[1]</sup>

<sub>[1] Petropoulos F., Makridakis S., Assimakopoulos V. & Nikolopoulos K. (2014) "'Horses for Courses' in demand forecasting", *European Journal of Operational Research*, Vol. 237, No. 1, pp. 152-163.</sub>

```
% Test in MATLAB 
D = simID(1,50000,2.5,2.5,3);

mean(D)                          % 1.2089
std(D)                           % 3.3913
```

```
# Test in R
# install.packages('tsintermittent')
library('tsintermittent')

D = simID(1,50000,2.5,2.5,3)
mean(D$ts.1)                      # 1.19632
sd(D$ts.1)                        # 3.261225
```

Values not in exact agreement due to not having the same random seed.

---

**MATLAB Code:** (tested with R2019a)

```
function [d] = simID(n, obs, adi, cv2, level)
% n: number of demand streams to create
% obs: number of time periods to simulate
% adi: average demand interval
% cv2: coefficient of variation squared
% level: average of nonzero demand 
%
% d: 'n' x 'obs' matrix with the specified demand streams
%
% If 'level' empty, defaults to sample from Uniform(10,100). 
% 
% MATLAB implementation of simID() from 'tsintermittent' package for R
% https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tsintermittent/versions/1.9/topics/simID
% https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=tsintermittent
%
% This simulator assumes that non-zero demand arrivals follow a bernoulli distribution 
% and the non-zero demands a negative binomial distribution. 
% Petropoulos F., Makridakis S., Assimakopoulos V. & Nikolopoulos K. (2014) 
% "'Horses for Courses' in demand forecasting", 
% European Journal of Operational Research, Vol. 237, No. 1, pp. 152-163

% Input Error Checking ****************************************************
narginchk(3,5)
if isempty(level), level = 10 + 90*rand(); end
if cv2<=0, error('cv2 must be positive'), end
if n<0 || obs<0 || adi < 0, error('n, obs, and adi must be positive'), end
if adi < 1, error('adi must be greater than 1'), end
% End (Input Error Checking) **********************************************

m = level - 1;
if ( cv2 ~= 0)
    p = (m / ( cv2 * ( (m+1)^2) ) ); % calculates the p for negative binomial function
    r = m * p / (1 - p); % calculates the r for the negative binomial function
    d = binornd(1, 1 / adi, n, obs) .* (nbinrnd(r, p, n, obs) + 1);
else
    d = binornd(1, 1/adi, n, obs) .* repmat(m + 1, n, obs);
end

end
```